# How do I add a single column from aggregate function into a SQL query?

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables, related by a single foreign key relationship. A simple example of this is a database with an `Accounts` table and an `Orders` table, in which `Orders.AcctID` has a foreign key relationship to `Accounts.AcctID`. I'm trying to create a single query that returns `Account.AcctID`, `Account.Name` and `Account.Email`, as well as the number of orders made by that account.

It's relatively easy to use the `COUNT()` aggregate function to get the number of orders for each account ID (see below), but if I try to add `Accounts.Name` and `Accounts.Email` to the query, SQL naturally tells me that those columns aren't part of the aggregate function.

There's got to be a way to embed the aggregate query as a sub-query or a join, but everything I've tried gives me a "FROM" syntax error, with no explanation as to how to fix it. Google searches have yielded nothing helpful, even though you'd think this should be a SQL 101 problem. Any advice would be phenomenal!

```
select 
    Accounts.AcctID, 
    count(Orders.OrderID) as OrderCount 
from 
    Accounts 
left join 
    Orders on Accounts.AcctID = Orders.AcctID 
group by 
    Accounts.AccountID
```

In short, I just want to return several columns from `Accounts`, plus the number of orders for that account. If there are no orders, 0 or NULL in the column is fine, but I need to see those accounts, too. I know I can do this with two separate queries, but this is for an application where a single query is what's expected.

Comment: Simply add those non-aggregated columns to your GROUP BY clause (comma separated). `GROUP BY Accounts.AccountID, Accounts.Name, Accounts.Email`

Comment: You can put your aggregation query into a CTE, then join back to your main accounts table on the AcctID. So rather than adding more columns to your aggregation, add your aggregation results to your columns... hope that makes sense. Ofcourse there are other ways to achieve this as well, but this would be the simplest. What @JNevill suggested also works if your Accounts are one to many to Orders as the naming may suggest.

Comment: I thought I had tried that and failed, but you nailed it! Thank you! This gets me 90% of the way, but how do I include the accounts that have no orders?

Comment: Use a `left join` not an `inner join`, and keep all conditions in the CTE or in the `on` not the outer `where`

Comment: FAB, the CTE approach might be the way to go, maybe even to get results for accounts that have zero orders, so far. An example would be awesome, but I am looking at a CTE tutorial. I've been working with SQL queries for more than a decade, but never got any formal training and have tons of holes in my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that account name and account email are unique per accountid.

```
declare @accounts table (AcctID int identity(1,1) not null, [Name] varchar(10) not null, Email varchar(20) not null)
declare @orders table (OrderID int identity(1,1) not null, AcctID int not null, OrderName varchar(20) not null)

insert into @accounts Values 
('Acc 1', 'aaa@bbb.com')
,('Acc 2', 'bbb@nnn.com')
,('Acc 3', 'ooo@ggg.com')
,('Acc 4', 'ooo@ggg.com')

insert into @orders Values
(1, 'order 1 4 acc 1'),(1, 'order 2 4 acc 1')
,(1, 'order 3 4 acc 1'),(2, 'order 1 4 acc 2')
,(2, 'order 1 4 acc 2'),(3, 'order 1 4 acc 3')

select 
    Accounts.AcctID, 
    Accounts.Name,
    Accounts.Email ,
    count(Orders.OrderID) as OrderCount 
from 
    @Accounts Accounts
left join 
    @Orders Orders on Accounts.AcctID = Orders.AcctID 
group by Accounts.AcctID, Accounts.Name, Accounts.Email
```

```
| AcctID | AccountName | AccountEmail | OrderCount |
| -------- | --------------- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1 | Acct 1 | aaa@bbb.com | 3 |
| 2 | Acct 2 | bbb@nnn.com | 2 |
| 3 | Acct 3 | ooo@ggg.com | 1 |
| 4 | Acct 4 | ooo@ggg.com | 0 |
```

try to see if you have any accounts without any orders:

```
select * from @Accounts Accounts
left join @Orders Orders on Accounts.AcctID = Orders.AcctID 
where orders.OrderID is null
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's really not liking the "AccountName = MAX(Accounts.Name)," section. I get "No value given for one or more required parameters," so either there's something I'm missing, or the interpreter doesn't support the syntax. If I just do a simple select using the MAX() function, that works fine, but not when combined with the count() function. At any rate, only AcctID and OrderID are guaranteed to be unique, so maybe MAX() isn't the best workaround.

Comment: i made adjustment, grouping by id, name and email, its possible you might have bad data.

Comment: Ah, well, now this is the same as my code, plus JNevill's proposed additional columns in the GROUP BY block. And it gets the same results as JNevill, which is only the accounts with one or more orders. It's close (and at least it's syntactically valid), but I really do also need those zero-order accounts in my results. Maybe the CTE approach will accomplish that. My source data is solid, so I know that's not an issue.

Comment: it will show zero on accounts wit no orders. but if you want orders without accounts - that would be a different query look in account 4 in example - it does not have any orders and shows zero

Comment: I don't understand why this is, but using the queries that we both have shared here, SQL Server 2022 only returns the Accounts that have at least one order. The query returns correct order counts for the 5 accounts that have orders, and omits the 9 that have no orders. Perhaps there's some sort of setting that dictates the behavior of query syntax, but I doubt it. The data shouldn't have any orders without an Account ID, but even if it did, those records would be excluded by the query.

Comment: check updated answer to see if any accounts dont have orders. and be sure you are using LEFT JOIN

Comment: It wants us to move this to the chat, but I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this. In your update, did you mean the WHERE clause to be "where orders.AcctID is null"? orders.OrderID is the primary key in that table and is not allowed to be null. So with orders.AcctID in the WHERE clause, I do indeed get the 9 accounts that have no orders; the data and all the queries are consistent. In your example, you created temporary data, but I'm using an actual database, so it's likely your SQL engine is doing something different with those tables, than mine is.

Comment: ok. because you are using LEFT JOIN means all rows on left side and matching rows on right side, if there are accounts without orders - the order id would be null value. so you can see accounts without any orders.

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/13/sql-server-warning-null-value-is-eliminated-by-an-aggregate-or-other-set-operation/

Answer (score 0):

JNevill's comment showed that I was on the right track, but needed to include all the columns that I wanted in the results in the GROUP BY clause. The back-and-forth with Power Mouse helped me realize that due to SQL Server's default choices, I must explicitly tell it that I want accounts with and without orders. The final query, that returns order counts for ALL accounts, along with the fields I wanted is:

```
select Accounts.AcctID, Accounts.Name, Accounts.Email, count(Orders.AcctID) As OrderCount
from Accounts left join Orders on Accounts.AcctID = Orders.AcctID
where Orders.AcctID is null or Orders.AcctID is not null 
group by Accounts.AcctID, Accounts.Name, Accounts.Email
```

Comment: that makes no sense.  you shouldn't need any where clause.  the query says return all accounts and a count of orders for each account (even if that count is 0) the where clause shoudln't be needed at all...

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  You shouldn't need any where clause see this example https://dbfiddle.uk/rLdO5vCH or https://dbfiddle.uk/UMWAee6c

Comment: I agree that it seems totally redundant, and yet, it's needed on both SQL Server 2022 and MS Access. I think it's part of the weirdness surrounding aggegate functions. I'm not comfortable with the solution, but there's no question that it only works this way.

Comment: Yeah I don't get it: https://dbfiddle.uk/-DXV7eZe works shows the right count for each account and orders even when an account has no orders.  The only way this wouldn't work is if you have other where clause criteria which negates the left join like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/l97FJOJ3  but in this case you move the limiting critieria to the join instead of where cluase....  such as: https://dbfiddle.uk/wisHL9KP  but *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a WITH

```
WITH wOrderCt AS
(    SELECT 
        Accounts.AcctID 
    ,    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as OrderCount 
    FROM Accounts 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders
        ON Orders.AcctID = Accounts.AcctID
    GROUP BY 
        Accounts.AcctID
)
SELECT
    Accounts.AcctID
,    Accounts.Email
,    Accounts.SomeOtherfield
,    wOrderCt.OrderCount
FROM wOrderCt
INNER JOIN Accounts
    ON Accounts.AcctID = wOrderCt.AcctID
;
```

OR

```
WITH wOrderCt AS
(    SELECT 
        Orders.AcctID 
    ,    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as OrderCount 
    FROM Orders 
    GROUP BY
        Orders.AcctID
)
SELECT
    Accounts.AcctID
,    Accounts.Email
,    Accounts.SomeOtherfield
,    ISNULL(wOrderCt.OrderCount, 0) AS OrderCount
FROM Accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN wOrderCt
    ON wOrderCt.AcctID = Accounts.AcctID
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the CTE example, RT72. I'll give these a try. Less compact than the other solution, but more adaptable and more readable, and hopefully not subject to the weird WHERE clause behavior.